# Put a sum as value in a hashmap

Tags: java, list, loops, hashmap, average

My two lists `list2` and `filetemp` are of the same lengths and contain dates and temperatures. A few of the elements in the lists are shown below:

```
[1946-01-12, 1946-01-12, 1946-01-12, 1946-01-13, 1946-01-13, 1946-01-13, 1946-01-14, 1946-01-14, 1946-01-14]
[-1.3, 0.3, -2.8, -6.2, -4.7, -4.3, -1.5, -0.2, -0.4]
```

I want to put them in a hashmap with dates as key and temperature as value. Since I have several temperature values corresponding to each date, I want to sum the temperature values for each day (or if possible calculate average temperature for each day) so that each date in the map corresponds to the average temperature of that date. My problem now is that my map looks like:

```
1946-01-12: -2.8
1946-01-13: -4.3
1946-01-14: -0.4
```

so instead of summing for example -1.5+(-0.2)+(-0.4) for date 1946-01-14 it just returns the last temperature of that date. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```java
public Map<LocalDate, Double> avarageTemperatures(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {
    List<LocalDate> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Weather weather : weatherData) {
        list2.add(weather.getDateTime());
    }

    Map<LocalDate, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Double> filetemp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Weather weather : weatherData) {
        filetemp.add(weather.getTemperature());
    }
    Double val= 0.0;
    for (int i=1; i<list2.size(); i++) {
        if(list2.get(i)==list2.get(i-1)) {
            val+= filetemp.get(i);
            map.put(list2.get(i), val);
        } else {
            val=filetemp.get(i);
            map.put(list2.get(i), val);
        }
    }

    Set<Map.Entry<LocalDate, Double>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<LocalDate,Double> entry : entrySet) {
        if(!entry.getKey().isAfter(dateTo) && !entry.getKey().isBefore(dateFrom)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and use semantic names, not such as ```entry : entrySet```. It's harder to read and since your question is basically asking people here to debug your code, you should make sure the code is as nice as possible.

Comment: Post the code needed to make this compile.

Comment: Are the dates always sorted? Because that could make this computation a bit easier

Comment: @Rogue Yes always sorted

Comment: Provided an answer to this that allows you to get the sum and average @Natalie_eds

Comment: Why are you creating two lists? There is a weather object that contains the date and corresponding temperature.

Comment: What's the type of `weatherData`? Is it a list? This is a one liner if you don't unpack your source to 2 lists first.

Comment: @AjahnCharles weatherData is an arraylist containing dateTime, Time, temperature and tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can do it. To get a List of Weather objects like you have we create a List of Weather objects using the array of String and array of Double values. From that List we simply collect using Collectors#groupingBy which allows us to determine the key we want to group by, which in this case is LocalDate, and the Collector used to group all the relevant key values together, which in this case is Collectors#summingDouble since we want to sum all double values.

```java
        String[] dates = {
                "1946-01-12", "1946-01-12", "1946-01-12", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13",
                "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14"
        };

        double[] temperatures = {-1.3, 0.3, -2.8, -6.2, -4.7, -4.3, -1.5, -0.2, -0.4};

        class Weather {

            private final LocalDate date;

            private final double temperature;

            Weather(LocalDate date, double temperature) {
                this.date = date;
                this.temperature = temperature;
            }

            public LocalDate getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public double getTemperature() {
                return temperature;
            }
        }

        List<Weather> weather = IntStream.range(0, dates.length)
                .mapToObj(index -> new Weather(LocalDate.parse(dates[index]), temperatures[index]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());        

       Map<LocalDate, Double> temperaturesSum = weather.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getDate,
                        Collectors.summingDouble(Weather::getTemperature)));

        Map<LocalDate, Double> temperaturesAverage = weather.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getDate,
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Weather::getTemperature)));

        System.out.println("sum: " + temperaturesSum);
        System.out.println("average: " + temperaturesAverage);
```

## Output

```
sum: {1946-01-12=-3.8, 1946-01-13=-15.2, 1946-01-14=-2.1}
average: {1946-01-12=-1.2666666666666666, 1946-01-13=-5.066666666666666, 1946-01-14=-0.7000000000000001}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand your solution. Do I have to create a List of Weather objects using the array of String like you did? Because my weather object contains like 20000 dates and temperatures.

Comment: No you absolutely do not need to create it the way I did. I had to do is this way because Weather was not provided and weatherData was not provided.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is one way using `streams` and creating a map of maps.  The inner map simply holds the `sum` and `average` temperatures.  A `List` could also have been used but the map allows symbolic indexing to help keep things straight.

It works as follows:

- Use the `Collectors.teeing` method to create two streams.  The first does a frequency count of dates.  The second, adds the temps.  Both end up in maps with the dates as keys.
- Then compute the average temp by dividing the sum by the frequency count of dates.  This allows the number of dates for each sample to vary in number and still allow an accurate average.
- Both the sum of temperatures and the average temperature are stored as a map.
- A `TreeMap` is used for the outer map to sort the keys in their natural order.

```
    List<String> dates =
            List.of("1946-01-12", "1946-01-12", "1946-01-12",
                    "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13",
                    "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14");

    List<Double> temps = List.of(-1.3, 0.3, -2.8, -6.2, -4.7,
            -4.3, -1.5, -0.2, -0.4);

    Map<String,Map<String, Double>> data = IntStream
            .range(0,
                    dates.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(i -> dates.get(i),
                            Collectors.counting()),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(i -> dates.get(i),
                            Collectors.summingDouble(
                                    i -> temps.get(i))),
                    (counts, temp) -> temp.keySet().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k,
                                    k->Map.of("SUM", temp.get(k), "AVG",temp.get(k)
                                            / counts.get(k)), (m,n)->n, TreeMap::new))));



    for (String k : data.keySet())  {
        System.out.printf("For %s - sum of temperatures was %6.3f%n",k,data.get(k).get("SUM"));
        System.out.printf("For %s - average temp was %6.3f%n",k,data.get(k).get("AVG"));
        System.out.println();
     }
```

It prints the following:

```
For 1946-01-12 - sum of temperatures was -3.800
For 1946-01-12 - average temp was -1.267

For 1946-01-13 - sum of temperatures was -15.200
For 1946-01-13 - average temp was -5.067

For 1946-01-14 - sum of temperatures was -2.100
For 1946-01-14 - average temp was -0.700
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("1946-01-12", "1946-01-12", "1946-01-12", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-13", "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14", "1946-01-14");
    List<Double> values = Arrays.asList(-1.3, 0.3, -2.8, -6.2, -4.7, -4.3, -1.5, -0.2, -0.4);

    Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> res = IntStream
            .range(0, dates.size())
            .boxed()
            .map(index -> new Pair<>(dates.get(index), values.get(index)))
            .collect(groupingBy(Pair::getKey,
                    summarizingDouble(Pair::getValue)));

    System.out.println(res);
```

and the result:

```
{1946-01-14=DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=-2.100000, min=-1.500000, average=-0.700000, max=-0.200000}, 
1946-01-12=DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=-3.800000, min=-2.800000, average=-1.266667, max=0.300000}, 
1946-01-13=DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=-15.200000, min=-6.200000, average=-5.066667, max=-4.300000}}
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately this does not provide the correct result. They do not want the last entry in the list, they want the sum of all entries.

Comment: No point in creating two lists ...  that is totally error and bug prone.  There is already a Weather object that holds the corresponding date and temperature value.  What if eventually the quantity of the two lists changes? Now we won't know if the dates and values match up.

Comment: Good job, one thing worth noting is that you don't need to call entrySet then stream, then map, then collect. On the first collect call just use Collectors#groupingBy and provide Pair::getKey and then instead of mapping again, call the Collectors#summingInt on Pair::getValue. This will provide you with a Map with distinct keys and the sum of all the values collected.